# KQL aggregation function product

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

I'm having the following table:

| productName | feature | probability_for _feature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | w | 0.2 |
| A | z | 0.8 |
| B | w | 0.2 |
| B | z | 0.8 |
| B | x | 0.3 |

I want to get for each productName the product of probability for it's feature meaning productName  A have both feature w with probability 0.2 and feature z with probability 0.8 hence the product for feature A will bee 0.2*0.8= 0.16.
Thus , in the table above I will get:

| productName | features | probability_for _feature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | [w,z] | 0.16 |
| B | [w,z,x] | 0.048 |

Or just :

| productName | probability |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.16 |
| B | 0.048 |

I didn't find any product or multiply function as aggregation function and would like to get some help .
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option, using a cumulative sum and leveraging the fact that `log(x1) + log(x2) … + log(xN) == log(x1 * x2 * … * xN)`:

```
datatable(productName:string, feature:string, probability_for_feature:double)
[
    'A', 'w', 0.2,
    'A', 'z', 0.8,
    'B', 'w', 0.2,
    'B', 'z', 0.8,
    'B', 'x', 0.3,
]
| order by productName asc 
| extend l = log10(probability_for_feature), rn = row_number()
| extend cumsum = row_cumsum(l, productName != prev(productName))
| summarize arg_max(rn, *), features = make_list(feature) by productName
| project productName, features, product = exp10(cumsum)
```

| productName | features | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | [ "w", "z" ] | 0.16 |
| B | [ "w", "z", "x" ] | 0.048 |

Answer (score 1):

For aggregation with any function you can use the scan operator.
[scan operator example cumulative sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator#cumulative-sum)
Example with multiply:

```
datatable (productName: string, feature: string, probability_for_feature: double)
[
        'A', 'w', 0.2,
        'A', 'z', 0.8,
        'B', 'w', 0.2,
        'B', 'z', 0.8,
        'B', 'x', 0.3,
]
| sort by productName asc
| partition by productName
(
    // for every productName scan all rows
    scan declare (probability: double= 1.0) with 
    (
        // multiply probability for every row and return last result
        step s1 output=last: true => probability = probability_for_feature * s1.probability;
    )
)
| project productName, probability
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).